# Getting the source code of an older version of an article?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, com-content, versions

I want to get the HTML source of an old version of an article from the version history without restoring it. I can only seem to get a rendered preview or a change list in HTML from the compare option.

Is this possible?

Comment: James, you now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 3):

Revisions are stored in the `#__ucm_content` table. The version number is the `core_version` field. If you want, for example, to get the body of the 2nd reversion of the article with ID 123, you issue the following query:

```
SELECT `core_body` FROM `#__ucm_content` WHERE `core_content_item_id` = '123' AND `core_version` = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. So I take it that this has to be done with server access, not through the administrator web portal?

Comment: You can probably install a DB extension that lets you do it via the admin section.